# How to re-set the key of an associative array using PHP?

Tags: php

Say I have the following array which is coming from this variable:

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($mul_from));
 echo '</pre>'

stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => from 1
            [1] => from 1
            [2] => from 1
            [3] => from 1
            [4] => from 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => from 2
            [1] => from 2
            [2] => from 2
            [3] => from 2
            [4] => from 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => from 3
            [2] => from 3
            [3] => from 3
        )

)
```

How can I re-set the key to 0 1 2 3 and so one? Currently, it's showing 0 1 3

Comment: [array_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)?

Comment: let's see this function

Comment: @lolbas It's seems working :)